# How can i put a text file in numerical order based on what it starts with?

Tags: c#

Here is an example of the text file...

```
7</DOdds>Some Text Here
4.5</DOdds>Some Text Here 
11</DOdds>Some Text Here
8.5</DOdds>Some Text Here
```

...Im trying to get the output file like this...

```
4.5</DOdds>Some Text Here
7</DOdds>Some Text Here
8.5</DOdds>Some Text Here
11</DOdds>Some Text Here
```

heres my code...

```
                foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(myfile))
                {
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(line);
                    var result = lines.AsParallel().OrderBy(s => s.Split('<').First()).ToList();
                    File.WriteAllLines(line, lines);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert to `double` the first element after *splitting* the *string*.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(myfile);
var result = lines.AsParallel().OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Split('<').First())).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(myfile, result);
```

Output

```
4.5</DOdds>Some Text Here 
7</DOdds>Some Text Here
8.5</DOdds>Some Text Here
11</DOdds>Some Text Here
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but would assume you can just add this to you code:

```
Convert.ToDouble()
```

Ie.

```
var result = lines.AsParallel().OrderBy(s => Convert.ToDouble(s.Split('<').First())).ToList();
```